Spring Boot - Disable db connection at the startup
This is regarding disabling the db connection at the startup. we do not want to connect to the db during the starting of the application.
I googled around and checked the previous questions in Stack overflow and checked the spring documentation to disabling the database connection at the startup. configuration suggested is exclude= [DataSourceAutoConfiguration]. below are the annotation on the SpringApplication class but the application fails and does not start.
@EnableAsync
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableJpaRepositories('org.*.*')
@EntityScan('org.*.*.domain.jpa')
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= [DataSourceAutoConfiguration]) 

getting following exception during the startup , AM I missing any configuration, Thanks for your help in advance.

Error creating bean with name 'annotationRepository' defined in
org...*.jpa.AnnotationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories
declared on Application: Cannot create inner bean '(inner
bean)#e30573c' of type
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e30573c': Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
argument; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available


Excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration alone is not sufficient when you're using JPA, because JPA requires a data source and the EntityManagerFactory for its operations.
When you exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration, the EntityManagerFactory bean will not be created, leading to the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException you're seeing. To resolve this, you can also exclude the JPA-related auto-configuration classes such as HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.
@EnableAsync
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.*.*")
@EntityScan("org.*.*.domain.jpa")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}


I have tried the suggested change but still facing same issue.
tired the following as well but nothing works
exclude= [DataSourceAutoConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration]
I am using Spring-boot 2.7.18
Thanks for your suggestion though. Am I missing any other configuration.

Any direction would be helpful.
